# Enter mathematical operators using input tag

Tags: python

I am using the following code for Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, and Division. Users will be entering the operator of their own choice. Is there a simple way to get the input from a user and display the result, instead of writing `if op=='+':`?

```python
num1 = int(input("Enter first number"))
num2 = int(input("Enter second number"))
op = input("Enter mathematical operator")
if op == '+':
    print("Result is ", num1+num2)
if op == '-':
    print("Result is ", num1-num2)
if op == '*':
    print("Result is ", num1*num2)
if op == '/':
    print("Result is ", num1/num2)
if op == '%':
    print("Result is ", num1%num2)
if op == '**'
    print("Result is ", num1**num2)
if op == '//':
    print("Result is ", num1//num2)
```

Comment: Related: [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](/q/60208/4518341)

Comment: What’s an input ‘tag’?

Comment: @user3840170 I bet they're thinking of HTML's [`<input>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)

Answer (score 4):

```
num1 = int(input("Enter first number"))
num2 = int(input("Enter second number"))
op = input("Enter mathematical operator")
if op in ('+', '-', '*', '/' , '//', '%', '**'):
    print("Result is", eval(f"{num1}{op}{num2}"))
else:
    print("Operator not recognized.")
```

`eval` is a dangerous function, because it can execute arbitrary Python code, but in this case I'm filtering the input so I know the expression is legitimate.